# A regular value theorem for algebraic varieties

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am wondering if we have a regular value theorem for algebraic varieties. Suppose we are working in the base field $\mathbb{C}$. My guess goes like this:

Suppose we have quasi-projective varieties $M$ and $N$ with dimensions $m$ and $n$, respectively. Consider a morphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ between algebraic varieties. Then if $c\in N$ is a regular value, then the set-theoretic preimage $f^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth subvariety of $M$ of dimension $m-n$.

Is it true? or do I need some modification?

Comment: One word: Flatness. Also see Hartshorne, chapter 2, exercise 3.22. This exercise is by no means as easy as the regular value theorem.